# Why is this ng-show directive not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

It seems I am missing something utterly obvious with this setup for `ng-show` in my angular 1.2.21 app (isolated the test case here). I want an element to show only if a string is not empty. Say I have a bit of dynamic, possibly empty, text with a static heading, and I don't want the whole element with the heading and empty text to show up when the text is empty.

[I tried like so (complete plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXcCdy34ZQpuIzm6AqJx?p=preview):

html:

```
<body ng-controller="FooController">
  foo: "{{ foo }}"
  <div>{{ rand }}</div>
  <div ng-show={{ foo }}>Hello foo{{ foo }}!</div>
  <div ng-show={{ bar }}>You ought to be hiding!</div>
</body>
```

and js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('FooController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.rand = Math.random();
      $scope.foo = $scope.rand > 0.5 ? "bar" : "";
      $scope.bar = false;
    }
  ]);
```

Now I'd expect the "Hello foobar" `<div>` only to show when the random value is > 0.5, and for double checking I added a `$scope.bar` which is false, so I would definitely expect the "You ought to be hiding!" `<div>` to be hidden.

However, they are not. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<body ng-controller="FooController">
  foo: "{{ foo }}"
  <div>{{ rand }}</div>
  <div ng-show="foo">Hello foo{{ foo }}!</div>
  <div ng-show="bar">You ought to be hiding!</div>
</body>
```

Your `ng-show` syntax is not correct. You shouldn't use `{{}}`.

Comment: Ah, right. I re-evaluated the value, when they are evaluated already. Still wrapping my head around angular syntax! Thank you.

Comment: @AbhinavGujjar No worries :) I couldn't accept it earlier because of the minimum expiration timer.